# How to change StatusBar textColor in iOS7

Tags: ios7, statusbar, uicolor

I need to change the color of `Status Bar` text in `iOS7`.

So i tried following codes.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

But it doesn't work and still showing white color like following pic.
I want to change to `black color`.

[image]

So how can i change it?

Comment: Did you try using the non-deprecated equivalent `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` (instead of `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque`)? Also, you may need to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in the plist file.

Comment: yes , i tried like you said. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Even the plist file change?

Comment: yes i changed UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO.

Comment: I have tried the same, doesn't work. Been scratching my head for days on this thing. plist, viewDidLoad, [UIApplication shareApplication]..